# Flash UI component not being 'repainted' when user uses browser zoom (only on Mac/Safari)

Tags: flash, safari

I have flash component in a website, which shows a preview.  There are some UI components overlaid on the preview to allow navigation.  Unfortunately it seems that in Safari on Macs, there is a problem:

When the user zooms in or out (using the browser based page zoom), my overlaid UI items disappear for some reason.  This does not happen on any other platform.

I would have though that this zoom function would be something that is taken care of solely by the browser/Flash plugin, however, perhaps there is something I can do to force a 'redraw'?

Has anyone else come across this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide an example that reproduces this problem, please?

Comment: @user8472 - that might not be possible unfortunately, but I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to replicate your scenario because of non specific descriptions.

1. What version of Flash are you using ?
2. Which components are you using(what are 'some UI components' ?
3. What is a 'preview' ? Is just an image, it is a complex item renderer ? If it's an image, how large is it ?
4. What do you mean by 'browser based zoom' ? Is it Flash Player's context menu Zoom In option ? Is it CMD+ ?

Without proper details I would advise you try [invalidate()](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/core/UIComponent.html#invalidate()), [validateNow()](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/core/UIComponent.html#validateNow()) or [drawNow()](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/core/UIComponent.html#drawNow())...maybe, just maybe.

Comment: 1. Built using Adobe Flash CS4 (the player causing problems is the latest version I believe).
2. The UI 'components' are just standard flash movieclip buttons.  3. Yes just and image (could be approx 200k), but I don't think this is relevant, the image is displaying fine.  4. Yes, the zoom functionality provided by the browser, not the flash player (ctrl + on firefox).

Regarding the functions you mention, when am I suppsed to call these?  As far as I know there is no 'onZoomed' event that I can hook into.

Comment: @UpTheCreek I'll have access to Flash CS4 tomorrow, so no solution yet. Thanks for clearing things out a bit. 2.) So you have some fl.controls.Button instances on top of an image(Loader, or something) and when you zoom in using the context menu(Zoom In), the buttons disappear , right ? 3.) I meant image dimensions(width,height). File is irelevant. Dimensions wise BitmapData instances are limited to 8192 pixels in width/height. I've got an idea for a 'handmade' onZoomed event

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The image is well within those dimension limits.

Comment: @UpTheCreek I've placed a ScrollPane with a large image and placed a Button(fl.controls) on top and had no problem zooming in. I can't seem to replicate your issue. Can you add steps for me to reproduce your scenario and spot the problem ? Also, for the 'onZoomed', have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374179/actionscript-3-contextmenu-closed-event/1376316#1376316

Answer (score 1):

This same problem recently began happening in Firefox and Safari, circa February 2011 if not earlier, somewhere about the time I upgraded Firefox to 3.6.1.3 and was then directed (by Firefox) to update Adobe Flash.